# What is the use case of entity inheritance strategies in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, inheritance, orm

I know very well about inheritance strategy like :

1.Table per Hierarchy

2.Table per Concrete class

3.Table per sub class

So they all are inheritance strategies for so on what basis we should choose it ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hibernate Inheritance** :

To achieve the inheritance in hibernate, Hibernate provides us to 3 different types of strategies.

> Hibernate Inheritance for table per class
>
> Hibernate Inheritance for table per concrete class
>
> Hibernate Inheritance for table per sub class

To map the inheritance classes  to database tables we can use any one of the above strategies. There is no concept of which one is best strategy, based on our application requirement we can choose one of the above.

**Hibernate Inheritance for Table per Class :**

We can select this strategy, if we want to save the data of all classes hierarchy in to a single table of database. For this table per class strategy along with the object details, hibernate will insert a special value called discriminator to identify a pojo class objects easily in a table.

**Hibernate Inheritance for Table per Concrete Class :**

This hibernate inheritance strategy is selected, when there is a need to store each concrete class objects of inheritance in separate tables of database. For this strategy discriminator is optional.

**Hibernate Inheritance for Table per Sub Class :**

We can choose this hibernate inheritance strategy, if we want to map a super class and its sub classes to its own tables of database. A sub class table has a primary key and it is also a foreign key to get the relation with super class table.

For more informations & examples : [Inheritance mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

Comment: Kindly rate my question so that i can rate you back , i am new user here

Comment: If my answer resolved your problem..accept it as a valid answer..if not you can ask for more informations..

Comment: Answer that you have given, i feel its not enough explanation, as i know if i use Table per sub class , in this one i will not have problem , for example suppose if you have one parent class Person, and two Concrete class Employee and Customer, in TPSC i can can store multiple role of Person , like a employee can be your customer , but we cant store this information in other two , so why should i go for them , we should always use TPSC strategy .

Comment: It depends on your needs , Hibernate provides 3 different types of strategies, so if in your case TPSC will handle your need,others will found TPCC or TPC more pratique for their needs..

Comment: Can you please brief that need ?

Comment: its already done in my answer..dont forget to check the documentation in the link..